# Best way to control access to functions in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Simple question: what is the best way to ensure that a function is only being called from inside my app? I just want to make sure that nobody could just type in the url and run it.

I've thought about using Auth, but I really don't need username/password protection. Then I thought about private/protected functions, but I've read that CakePHP doesn't handle with that very well. And if I use private, as an example, I wouldn't be able to call the protected function from another controller class.

I think there must be a simply solution to this, but I can't think of one.

Thank you all in advance. :)

Comment: Could you tell us where you read that Cake has problems with private/protected? I've always used that (with PHP 5), and never had a problem. It works just like the underscore prefix. When you say you "wouldn't be able to call the protected function from another controller class", are you instantiating a controller inside another controller? In that case, you should be using a component, as @pleasedontbelong and @ElGabbu suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have functions that are been used in different controllers, it would be better if you create a component.

But.... if you really need to.. if you really want to.. you could set the access by adding an underscore at the beginning of your method's name:

```
class ProductsController extends AppController {

     // a browser can "access" this method
     function iHaveAView(){
     }

     // this method is used only by controllers
     function _cantTouchMe(){
     }
```

Good Luck

**EDITED:** (finally found the doc about this)

> You can also change the visibility of controller methods in CakePHP by
>   prefixing controller method names with underscores. If a controller
>   method has been prefixed with an underscore, the method will not be
>   accessible directly from the web but is available for internal use.

*source:* [Controller Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/compare/25/Controller-Conventions/cakephp/cakephp1x)

Comment: That's what I was looking for. You answered my question and even gave me tip on what I was doing wrong. Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 1):

I think it's simple don't put the function as an action of a controller. Create a component and use that when you need it.

That would make your function unavailable to the public but available within your app.

What do you think?